# Onsen UI After log in verified with Angular from mysql, how can I show my main screen?

Tags: mysql, angularjs, onsen-ui

My app has more than 10 screens and i want for programming order to keep each screen to different html file. In the index file I have the log in screen and in the angular controller I make the connection to the MySQL DB and it returns the response from DB. Now how can I call the main profile page (profile.html)?

my JS code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('Appname', ['onsen.directives']);
myApp.controller("LogInController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.errors = [];
    $scope.msgs = [];
    $scope.login = function () {

        $scope.errors.splice(0, $scope.errors.length);
        $scope.msgs.splice(0, $scope.msgs.length);

        $http.post('http://192.168.1.2/login.php', {'u':"Username", 'p':"Password"}).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.posts = data;
            console.log(data);
            alert(data[0].msg);
            //here I want to put main page profile.html
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert(data);
    });

}});
```

If I don't use the right approach, can you suggest me another example??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this clue would help.
Can you try out something like this.

```
$scope.ons.navigator.pushPage('profile.html');
```

Comment: Thx. It was helpfull, plus to work it needed the <ons-navigator> in the index file inside the controller's tag